# Why is the result of conditional operator opposite of expected?

Tags: java, operators

```
Object myObject = true ? new Integer(25) : new Double(25.0);

System.out.println(myObject);
```

Strangely, it outputs 25.0 instead of 25

Whats going on?

Comment: Wild guess: unboxing followed by a reboxing; and in the unboxing phase, your `int` gets converted to a `double`. If you do `new Integer(13)` for instance I wager that the result would be `13.0`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code returns the second operand (`new Integer(25)`) as you expected, but it converts it to a `Double` due to the following rules.

Here's what [JLS 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) says :

> if the second and third operands have types that are convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric types, then there are several cases:
>
> - If one of the operands is of type byte or Byte and the other is of type short or Short, then the type of the conditional expression is short.
> - If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.
> - If one of the operands is of type T, where T is Byte, Short, or Character, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type int whose value is representable in the type U which is the result of applying unboxing conversion to T, then the type of the conditional expression is U.
> - **Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands**. 
>     
>   Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).

And the numeric promotion :

> 5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion
>
> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> **If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion** (§5.1.8).
>
> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> **If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double**.

In your example, you have an `Integer` and a `Double`. They are unboxed to `int` and `double` and then the `int` is converted to a `double`.

Answer (score 3):

There is some wierd autoboxing stuff going on - you can see it better if you use different numbers:

```
    Object myObject = true ? new Integer(25) : new Double(22.0);
```

Now, myObject will still be assigned a Double(25.0), not the 22.0 you would expect if the conditional didn't work. Basically, because Java thinks you are doing some sort of calculation involving an int and a double it returns the result of the iif as a "double" primative and then autoboxes it back to a Double().

You could also get it to behave as expected by forcing it to treat the values as type Object():

```
    Object myObject = true ? (Object) new Integer(25) : (Object) new Double(22.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

After compilation

`Object myObject = true ? new Integer(25) : new Double(25.0);`

will be something as below

`Object myObject = (double) new Integer(25);`

**So, it returns new Integer(25) as expected but it gets converted to double.**

As Eran mentioned, as per [JLS 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and
>   the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the
>   second and third operands.
>
> 1. **If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).**
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - **If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double**.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
>        to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
>        to long.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.